# Java 8 and 9 compatibility

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, compatibility, java-9

I have a Java (JavaFX) project that I would like to run on java 8 and 9. 
This application uses some external, "user-created" libraries and one of them imports 
packages from jdk8 which are unavailable (restricted) in java 9. 
Without this one library everything works fine on both java versions, but if I want to use its features the program won't start on java 9.

I've tried editing the library's source code, replacing problematic imports with their jdk9 counterparts, but of course then it would run on java 9 only.
I've also tried to put source code of every needed class into the library files before building jar, and this would work, but it seems stupid and unsafe, and 
it's hard because of the number of required classes.

Is it possible and safe to add whole jdk8 libraries (or libs with equivalent classes from java9) with desired packages to the project? 
Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: Short answer: no. The bottom line is that if your app, or a library on which it depends, uses non-public API, it will not be backward compatible. You will need to create different versions of your application for Java 8 and Java 9 (using a version of the library that is Java 9 compatible).

Comment: That appears to be the classic usecase for *Multi-release Jars* introduced in Java 9. See [here](https://blog.codefx.org/tools/multi-release-jars-multiple-java-versions/) for an introduction.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. 
Most of the 'wrong' classes were from unsupported sun or com.sun APIs, internal, as you said, so it's pretty common issue. It's a shame there isn't any simple workaround to make it accessible in j9, but I guess it wouldn't be safe anyway. 

Right now I'm trying to create java 9 version of the library, so maybe I can merge it into this multi-release jar with j8 version. However, it's hard to find alternatives to some classes in jdk9.

Comment: Maybe you should first look at alternative classes in Java 8 (public API) or in external libraries. If you first look at Java 9 classes then you run into trouble if they are not available. Making the internal classes available again is *not a good idea*. Previously they were commonly left untouched because people abused them. That's unlikely to be true now that they are hidden within the modular system.

Comment: If a library can’t solve your task unless you hack into its internals, using it in an unintended way, you should rethink whether you are using the right library…